# Accidentally typed crontab with just the dash

Tags: shell, cron

What happens when I type just `crontab -`?

The `e` didn't take before I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It just moved the cursor to the next line and I had to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit, but I'm not sure what it did exactly.

I'm on Linux CentOS 6.3.

Answer (score 13):

That actually depends on what you did after that.

`crontab -` is interpreted as a variation on the `crontab file` invocation, where you change the current user's crontab with that contained in the specified file.

`-` in this case, as is common practice, means to read from `stdin` instead of an actual file.

The result of this is that if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> or otherwise aborted `crontab` nothing happened. On the other hand, if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd> (essentially `eof`), ending the input normally, then the `crontab` was replaced by whatever you had entered previous to that (possibly emptying it if nothing had been entered).

Comment: I hit Ctrl+D so that explains why doing crontab -e resulted in a blank file :( oh well lesson learned, must use Ctrl+C instead.